# Problems with Mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Game schema**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const gameSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: String,
  calc: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Calc' }]
});

module.exports = model('Game', gameSchema);
```

**Calc schema**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const calcSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  preset: { type: String, required: true },
  datasets: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Dataset' }],
  model: String,
});

module.exports = model('Calc', calcSchema, 'calc');
```

**GET Games route**

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
  Game.find()
    .select('_id name calc')
    .populate('calc')
    .then(games => res.status(200).json(games))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: err }));
});
```

Instead of populating calc property with Calc objects, replacing the ids, calc property turns into an empty array. How do I use populate correctly? Is there an obvious mistake I made in my code?

In short: populate() results in calc: [] instead of calc: [{Calc object}, ...]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is very unclear for now to understand your question and the problem you are facing. Please edit you question as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are trying to populate an array of document (and not only one document) so you should use the [Model.populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) method instead.

```
Game.find()
  .select('_id name calc')
  .then(games => Game.populate(games, { path: 'calc' }))
  .then(games => res.status(200).json(games))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ error: err }));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `.then(games => Game.populate({ path: 'calc' }))` triggers the catch block.. err is an empty object.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the first parameter. This is Game.populate(games, { path: 'calc' })